# What is the ideal career for a marketing + computer science post-graduate?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, careers

Currently, I am pursuing a master's degree in marketing at a business school.

As I have always been interested in mathematics and computer science, I plan to start an undergraduate degree in computer science in the meantime.

This is possible because attendance is not mandatory and I have two free months between semesters and one month after the end of the year.
These three months will be devoted to preparing for the computer science exams.

It won't be difficult for me, because I already do programming as a hobby.

My question is: what is the ideal career for someone with a master's degree in marketing and a master's degree in computer science? A position where the combination of the two is highly appreciated.

Do you think it's worth it?

Comment: CRM - Data scientists and HTML developers are key within this industry now-a-days and your background with marketing will give you a good leg up. Source: I used to work for a data driven marketing agency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could become a product owner in a company that delivers software products and head a team of developers with personal focus on organizational work (project management), not development (coding) itself.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the ideal career for a marketing + computer science post-graduate?

Pretty much the same as for everyone else.

Basically a high paying job, with interesting and fun work, which recognises you as a hero.

> Is it worth it?

All formal certifications that are internationally recognised are good to have and can be  big boost to career.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the ideal career for someone with a master's degree in marketing and a master's degree in computer science?

With that combination, you'd be an ideal candidate for a data science role. If you get into the right company, it can also be a very rewarding career with lots of interesting challenges to solve. It can be difficult for companies to find candidates that have both high level technical skills *and* marketing domain knowledge so having both degrees would put you in a very favorable position career-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You have a many routes,

1. Project Management
2. Product Owner
3. Growth Engineer
4. Business Analyst
5. Business Intelligence